# How can I connect a storyboard UISearchBar to a programmatically created UISearchController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I previously had a `searchController.searchBar` in the header view of my `UITableView` but I wanted to add buttons to change what array is displayed. Now that I've added a `UISearchBar` in my storyboard I'm trying to figure out how to connect it to my `UISearchController` so I can update the results properly. However, even in the newest XCode we still have `UIDisplayController` in the IB.

Two ways I think can solve this, either there's a way to connect them and I don't know it or I just use the searchBar native to the searchController and shift it's frame to where I want it. I'm hesitant to try the latter because of the benefits of AutoLayout for sizing.

Answer (score 1):

I always just put a placeholder view in the interface builder file that is 44 points tall.  You can then add the SearchController.view as a child of this container view.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var searchContainerView: UIView!

    fileprivate lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
        let contactSearchViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: ContactSearchViewController.self)) as! ContactSearchViewController
        contactSearchViewController.delegate = self
        contactSearchViewController.datasource = self
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: contactSearchViewController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = contactSearchViewController
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
        return searchController
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchContainerView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
        let attributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.top, .bottom, . left, .right]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(attributes.map{NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.searchController.searchBar, attribute: $0, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.searchContainerView, attribute: $0, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)})
    }
```